# HTML5 Custom video player doesn't work when i insert the video within a function

Tags: javascript, html, video, custom-controls

Hi all first of all thanks for the time to read my question and your help

I'm having the next issue with a customizing video controls in html5

In the next link i insert the video tag directly on the body and custom the video controls with the main.js

http://pechacabeza.com/labs/Webo/video/

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="container" onclick="screenad.click();"></div>
        <video id='media-video' controls poster="video_poster.jpg" autoplay muted class="adrime_video">
            <source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
            <source src='video.webm' type='video/webm'>
        </video>

        <div id='media-controls'>
            <progress id='progress-bar' min='0' max='100' value='0'></progress>
            <button id='replay-button' class='replay' title='replay' onclick='replayMedia();'></button>
            <button id='play-pause-button' class='play' title='play' onclick='togglePlayPause();'></button>
            <button id='mute-button' class='mute' title='mute' onclick='toggleMute("false");'></button>  
    </div>
</body>
```

The point is that i want to insert the video within a function *initialiseMediaPlayer* which is inside the main.js but then the custom video controls doesn't work :S as you can see in the next link:

http://pechacabeza.com/labs/Webo/video_Dynamic/

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="container" onclick="screenad.click();"></div>
        <div id='media-controls'>
            <progress id='progress-bar' min='0' max='100' value='0'></progress>
            <button id='replay-button' class='replay' title='replay' onclick='replayMedia();'></button>
            <button id='play-pause-button' class='play' title='play' onclick='togglePlayPause();'></button>
            <button id='mute-button' class='mute' title='mute' onclick='toggleMute("false");'></button>  
    </div>
    <div id="media-video"></div>


</body>
```

Any idea what it could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see it's play after few sec to load...

Comment: Hi Ben Mack thanks for your response :) but i barely could read it it seems the whole response is missing

it's play after few sec to load?